# How to remove a simple specific key value pair from all objects and add to one specific object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to add a key and value(i.e. age:15) to an object which has name as email and remove it(age) from other objects for the below array of object.

```js
[
  {
    name: 'test',
    lname: 'last',
    age: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'test1',
    lname: 'last1',
    age: 15
  },
  {
    name: 'email',
    lname: 'last',
  },
]
```

i.e. I want the below output.

```js
[
  {
    name: 'test',
    lname: 'last'
  },
  {
    name: 'test1',
    lname: 'last1'
  },
  {
    name: 'email',
    lname: 'last',
    age: 15
  },
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods). What exactly is the problem? Where in the process of writing the code are you stuck?

Comment: Please donot post a requirement without any valid attemepts or mentioning the difficlty that you are facing. Please not SO is not a freelance website, where you can post the requirement and someone will work and povide you the solution. We are here to help when you face any and not to write entire code for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is find the index of the object that has `name` as "email". Once you find the object, add the desired age value as a new property called `age`. Finally, you can use `filter` to filter the items that doesn't have `name` as "email" and delete the `age` property.

```js
var data = [ { name: 'test', lname: 'last', age: 5 }, { name: 'test1', lname: 'last1', age: 15 }, { name: 'email', lname: 'last', }, ]

function myFunction(age) {
  let indexOfEmail = data.findIndex(element => element.name == "email")
  if (indexOfEmail > -1) {
    data[indexOfEmail].age = age
    data.filter(element => element.name !== "email").map(sub => delete sub['age'])
  }
}

myFunction(15)
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Please try to avoid answering a question where the user has not tried anything to acheve the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `map` method, like this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'test',
    lname: 'last',
    age: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'test1',
    lname: 'last1',
    age: 15
  },
  {
    name: 'email',
    lname: 'last',
  },
];
const newData = data.map(({age, ...rest})=> rest.name == 'email' ? {...rest, age: 15} : rest)
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Won't this remove the age of all object even if there is no name such as "email"?

Comment: Please try to avoid answering a question where the user has not tried anything to acheve the result.

Comment: @Deepak your point is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```js
const items = [
  {
    name: 'test',
    lname: 'last',
    age: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'test1',
    lname: 'last1',
    age: 15
  },
  {
    name: 'email',
    lname: 'last',
  },
];

const newItems = items.filter((item) => {
    if (item.name.includes("email")) {
      return (item.age = 15);
    }
    if (JSON.stringify(items).includes("email")) {
      delete item.age;
    }
    return item;
});

console.log(newItems);
```

Comment: Please try to avoid answering a question where the user has not tried anything to acheve the result.